# Unity - Make crosshair appear when hovering over object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, raycasting

I've been at this for a few hours, I'm trying to make it so when shooting a raycast and it collides with an object with a certian tag, the crosshair is enabled, and if not hitting the object with the tag, it goes away. It appears to be a lot harder than I expected and I'm getting weird results.

either the cross hair appears if I click first, or it does work and the crosshair just won't disable again. Here is the code to the object interaction script. Please, let me know what I am doing wrong, thank you!

```
    public Collider clickObject;
    public Animator m_Animator;

    [SerializeField] public GameObject Crosshair;

    private Ray _ray;
    private RaycastHit _hit;
    private bool _opened;

    void Start()
    {
        m_Animator = gameObject.GetComponent<Animator>();
        Crosshair.SetActive(false);
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Click();
        }
    }

    private void Click()
    {
        if (!clickObject) return;
        if (!m_Animator) return;

        _ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(_ray, out _hit))
        {
            if (_hit.collider.CompareTag("InteractObject"))
            {
                Crosshair.SetActive(true);
            }
            else
            {
                Crosshair.SetActive(false);
            }

            if (_hit.collider == clickObject)
            {
                if (_opened)
                {
                    m_Animator.SetBool("isOpen", true);
                    _opened = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    m_Animator.SetBool("isOpen", false);
                    _opened = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing should happen as clickobject never gets set

Comment: when should i reference it?

Comment: its your code :P i dont know what you want it for, so you need to set it at some point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it seems you only raycast and update your cross-hair in your `Click()` function which you only call when you press your left mouse button:

```
    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Mouse0))
        {
            Click();
        }
    }
```

I think you want to call it every frame instead if you want the cross-hair to appear and disappear without any user input.

Comment: like should i create a function called, "active cross hair" and when the mouse button is clicked, it'll show up? But I also want to make it appear when looking at the object

Answer (score 0):

For this purpose, I suggest you to use **PointerRay** in [**RaycastPro**](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/raycastpro-214714). In this case, you will have good control over the Stamp and Ray of your camera.

[image: PointerRay]

Auxiliary events to turn off or use Stamp auto hide, whichever you want.

[image: Events]

Add your CrossHair as a Stamp to the Ray and set it as below. make sure that **AutoHide** and **stampOnHit** are enabled.

[image]